# How to have Mono from @PathVariable without blocking

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Hi i would like know how to have in my controller without any blocking code transformation from two arguments to Mono of DTO class.

Suppose I have controller like below:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class GithubRepositoryEndpoint {

    private final GithubService githubService;

    @GetMapping("/repositories/{owner}/{repositoryName}")
    Mono<RepoDetailsResponseDTO> getRepositoryDetails(@PathVariable("owner") String owner,
                                                      @PathVariable("repositoryName") String repositoryName) {
        return githubService.getRepositoryDetails(Mono.just(new RepoDetailsRequestDTO(owner, repositoryName)));
    }
}
```

I think this line is blocking:
Mono.just(new RepoDetailsRequestDTO(owner, repositoryName)

and here is DTO class:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RepoDetailsRequestDTO {
    private String owner;
    private String repositoryName;
}
```

My service is not blocking:

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GithubService {

    private final GithubClient githubClient;
    private final RequestValidator requestValidator;
    private final DomainMapper domainMapper;

    public Mono<RepoDetailsResponseDTO> getRepositoryDetails(Mono<RepoDetailsRequestDTO> request) {
        return request.map(requestValidator::validate)
                .map(domainMapper::mapFromDto)
                .flatMap(ownerAndRepoName -> githubClient.fetchRepositoryDetails(ownerAndRepoName._1, ownerAndRepoName._2))
                .onErrorResume(exc -> Mono.error(new FetchRepoDetailsException(exc.getMessage(), exc)));
    }


}
```

Comment: what makes you think that line is blocking? As far as I know the only time that blocking would occur is if you explicitly call .block() or .subscribe()

Answer (score 1):

the line

```
Mono.just(new RepoDetailsRequestDTO(owner, repositoryName))
```

is not blocking. It is just a constructor invocation. It does not use any blocking APIs (e.g. io/file/network). Both parameters *owner* and *repositoryName* can be safely accessed as they already contain the parsed path variables.